# PHP: Running out of memory

Tags: php, memory

Without changing the naïve algorithm below, what should I change to make the code less impactful on the memory? (The algorithm aims to solve project euler problem 31 [link](https://projecteuler.net/problem=31)

I think my algorithm works as it gives the correct answer when the max sum is 100.

When I try and run the code below for 200 it runs out of memory. This code below is not meant to be optimized just a simple implementation of an algorithm. I don't understand why this below cannot succeed with max sum = 200 since the answer isn't huge enough to not be bruteforce-able (google). I guess I'm doing something below that is very bad etiquette and I post this hoping someone could point that out to me, and perhaps give their way of implementing the algorithm.

```
<?php
$coinSet = array(200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1);
$coinCombo = array();
$sum_max = 100;
$test = array($sum_max);
$counter = 0;

function isValid($array){
    global $sum_max;
    if (array_sum($array) > $sum_max) {return (FALSE);}
    return (TRUE);
}

function isComplete($array){
    global $sum_max;
    if (array_sum($array) == $sum_max) {return (TRUE);}
    return (FALSE);
}

function split($array){
    global $coinSet;
    $array = array_filter($array, function($n) {return ($n > 1);});
    $element = array_search(end($array), $coinSet);
    $array[key($array)] = $coinSet[$element+1];
    reset($array);
    return $array;

}

function addElement($array){
    $array[] = end($array);
    return $array;
}

function solver($array){
    global $sum_max;
    global $coinCombo;
    global $counter;
    if (count($array) == $sum_max) { $counter++; return; }
    if (isComplete($array)) { $counter++; $array = split($array); }
    if (!isValid($array)) { $array = split($array); }
    if (isValid($array) & !isComplete($array)) { $array = addElement($array); }
    solver($array);

}

solver(array($sum_max));
print_r($counter);

?>
```

Comment: increase it then or set it to `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that modifying your array inside a function copies the array. Since you're doing this several times over with an array of size 200, this quickly becomes taxing for your memory. A solution might be to use the reference operator `&` in your function descriptions: `split(& $array)`. However, I'd certainly suggest you try something a little less taxing for this Coin Change Problem using Dynamic Programming and if that isn't enough, possibly giving up on part of the memorization.

Comment: Implementing references and increasing memory size solved my issue. Thank you for the input.

Comment: Great to hear :). If you either accept the answer or close the question otherwise might be helped too.